# In which case will the physical size of a file be smaller than the logical size?

Tags: linux, file, unix, filesystems

Usually, the physical size of a file is larger than the logical size. I was wondering whether there was any case for which the reverse is true. There could be certain files, for which physical size would be less than the logical size.

Comment: This question should not be closed.

Comment: I can't understand why people want to put this question as hold. When I discussed this question with some of my university friends, they were surprised to see the response given as below, which says yes, there are some cases. Because, literally we didn't know that this case could be possible. So, I think this is an interesting question. Please give enough reason why some of you don't want this question to be placed here?

Comment: The good news is that the reopen queue is a lot shorter than the close queue.

Comment: Thanks o11c. I hope they will reopen it soon.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C and nothing to do with programming and as such should not be asked here.

Answer (score 10):

With a modern file system like ZFS, there are three ways that allow the physical size of a file to be smaller than its logical one:

- Sparse files, where data blocks containing only zeroes are not physically stored. This is supported by most current file systems but excluding FAT and HFS+.
- Compressed files, where the OS is using a compression algorithm to store the data in less than its original size. ZFS, btrfs and HFS+ are implementing data compression.
- Deduplicated files, where blocks pertaining to different files but having the very same content are stored only once. This is implemented at least by ZFS, btrfs, vxfs and NTFS VHDs (Windows Server 2012.)

Snapshots and clones are also techniques that allow multiple files having a common origin but a diverging content to have only their difference stored, leading to a gain in disk space.

One can add hardlinks which allow multiple "files" (more precisely paths) to share the same data.

Finally, symbolic links store no data but the file they point to, if any, usually has a non null data size.

Comment: Fun fact, there was a [major bug in grep 2.13](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/829) because they assumed the only case was sparse files.

Comment: @o11c Thanks fore the link, interesting bug indeed !

Answer (score 6):

The most common case where this is true is in [sparse files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). These files are physically smaller than their logical size, because not all of their extents are allocated — there are "holes" in the file.

Note that not all filesystems support sparse files. (In particular, FAT does not.)

Comment: Thanks. Got it. However, what's the significance of those holes in a sparse file? Is it only to specify metadata?

Comment: @beginner: if you read the file, the missing blocks appear to be full of zeros (binary zeros, not the character '0'.)

Answer (score 1):

Physical size of file is *typically* the sum of all of the blocks assigned to the file, while the logical size is the actual usage of those blocks. To have a file *logically* larger than its *physical* size would imply that some data can be generated on the fly (since it has more than the blocks can hold).

You can achieve that concept by compressing the file and hiding the compression in the details of the filesystem driver. In this fashion you might have two 512-byte blocks supporting 1024 physical bytes but decompressing the data might reveal more than 1024 logical bytes in the file.

There are other nontrivial ways to accomplish what you ask but I don't think you're going to encounter them in the wild (unless you're working in a very niche corner of the world).